# how to add items to sharepoint hosted list from from sharepoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, sharepoint-on-prem

i wish to add item to share Point hosted list from  from share Point hosted app itself.here i tried something with the help of rest API's but that is not working,so how can i do this??

Answer (score 1):

CREATE Operation

listName: The name of the list you want to get items from

weburl: The url of the web that the list is in.

newItemTitle: New Item title.

success: The function to execute if the call is sucesfull

failure: The function to execute if the call fails

```
function CreateListItemWithDetails(listName, webUrl, newItemTitle, success, failure) {
var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
var item = {
    "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
    "Title": newItemTitle
};

$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(item),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        success(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        failure(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: i tried the same but here the hosted list name is missing,for the list name there i am getting 404 error,but when i m creating a list manualy insite site collection with same name then this code is working